# Refresh page ONCE

Tags: javascript, reload

I would like to implement a JavaScript code which states this: if the page is loaded completely, refresh the page immediately, but only once. This one works fine:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

but I don't want hash at the end.  Any solution?

Comment: Why? There might be a better solution to your problem

Answer (score 3):

use `cookies` or `localStorage`

```
window.onload = function() {
    if(!localStorage.loaded) {
        localStorage.setItem('loaded', 'yes')
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely an effective method to do what OP is asking.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working ;<

Comment: try this [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ShhzLhohUio7cl8a?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)

Comment: It worked only on main page and only once. 
Here is my website: https://www.mkally.com/demo/

I want a script that is working exactly like this one with function: window.location.hash - page is reloaded at once, script is working on entire site, there is no delay, timeout interval, etc. The only problem is that hash - I don't want it.

Comment: you need to create unique localStorage value for every page

Comment: Sory, I'm not a programmer. I tried to define a script to refresh HOME page. I added to this script something like:
 
 if(!localStorage.loaded === 'Home') {
  window.location = "http://www.mkally.com/demo/";

It's not working, so I suppose it's wrong. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

If first time will loaded then you have to set the hash ('loaded'). The automatically will reload the page. Second time he will found the hash #loaded in the url and dont reload the page again.

**To avoid hash in the url** you can use cookie or localStorage.

LocalStorage: In this case take a look to the answer from @uingtea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71373469/14807111.

```js
window.onload = function() {  
  if(window.location.hash !== '#loaded') {            
    window.location.hash = '#loaded';
    window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

**With cookie**

```js
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  let expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}


function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}



window.onload = function() {  
  if(getCookie('loaded')) {            
    setCookie('loaded','true',180);
    window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

Comment: The author of this question specifically said: `but I don't want hash at the end. Any solution?`. This solution requires a hash.

Comment: @HeyHoo  you are right. i will updated.

Comment: I think @uingtea has already got the win for this question, but if you do come up with a better solution then +1.

Comment: @HeyHoo Yes, he definitely won this round! I added the option with cookies. Thanks for your good comments!

Comment: You may of overcomplicated the code, but this seems also affective!